# Command .copyto is failing

Tags: android, opencv

I'm a student and I'm working on application that will scann a sudoku and solve it. I'm taking picture, than finding biggest contour. This is what is working.Problem begin when I want to extract that biggest counter on the empty mat (it has white backround), application don't show activity with picture that should (in other images it does) but it return to my mainactivity. I was using this tutorial for the extraction: https://bytefish.de/blog/extracting_contours_with_opencv/.

```
mat4=mat1; // mat 1 is current frame on camera
transpose(mat4, mat4);
flip(mat4, mat4, +1);
mat5=mat4;
Mat okraje = new Mat();
Mat hiearchy = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(mat5,mat5,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
List<MatOfPoint> contourList = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Imgproc.Canny(mat5,okraje,80,100);

Imgproc.findContours(okraje,contourList,hiearchy,Imgproc.RETR_CCOMP, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE); // TOPKA JEBNE PLNY STVOREC A KRATKO!!

for(int ab=0;ab < contourList.size(); ab++ ){
  a = contourArea(contourList.get(ab),false);
  if(a>largest_area){
    b=ab;
    largest_area = a;
    largest_contour_index=ab;
    bounding_rect=boundingRect(contourList.get(ab));
  }
}

Mat len_sudkoku = new Mat();
len_sudkoku.create(mat5.rows(), mat5.cols(),CvType.CV_8UC3);
len_sudkoku.setTo(new Scalar(255,255,255));

Mat lskere = new Mat();
lskere.create(okraje.cols(), okraje.rows(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
Random r = new Random();
Imgproc.drawContours( lskere, contourList,largest_contour_index, new Scalar(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255)), -1);
mat5.copyTo(len_sudkoku,lskere); // pada to!!

Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(len_sudkoku.cols(),len_sudkoku.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(len_sudkoku,bm);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_fotka_ukaz);
ImageView IMW = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    IMW.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

I expected to be like in tutorial that I posted here where a man extracted an apple and place it on another backround. Thing that I notice is that application return to main activity (it should display image), when I'm using a command

```
mat5.copyTo(len_sudkoku, lskere)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys i solved it. The problem wasn't in command copy to (obviously) but in declaration size of different mat and bitmap. The problem was that in declaration first input was sometimes row and column so it crashed. Now I add size to Mat hierarchy and okraje, and edit lskere.create(okraje.cols(), okraje.rows(), to lskere.create(okraje.rows(), okraje.cols()..